# Guess when mouse goes closer to launcher to auto-unhide it

Tags: unity, mouse, launcher, autohide

I would use auto-hide feature of the launcher but it's a bit annoying that it doesn't react in a sensitive enough way. Wonder if there is a way to make the launcher appear even before I touch the edge of left screen side? Like by 50px would suffice. I don't mind launcher appearing more often when I don't intend.

ps. Of course it would be great if Unity could guess by mouse inertia when the user intents to seek the launcher (but that's more of a futuristic feature request)

Comment: This *can* be done, but the launcher would pop up in a less elegant way than with autohide. would that bother you?

Comment: You mean without animation? How do you achieve that?

Comment: We can check the moiuse position, unset autohide if the mouse is within n-pixels from the left side, set it again when the mouse leaves the area. The launcher pops in brutally then however, pushing existing windows to the right.

Comment: Hi Aurimas, could you mention what you think of that ^.?

Comment: Hey, I actually started using Plank dock, which I feel is more sensitive and together with Unity launcher seems to fulfill my needs. But if you know an exact solution of how to do what you are describing, I would gladly try it out!

Answer (score 0):

I realize this isn't exactly the answer you want, but perhaps this approach will improve your experience. If you don't mind it appearing when you don't intend it to you could simply turn the auto-hide feature off by flipping the toggle shown as on in the picture below to off.

Another thing you could try to make the launcher more responsive would be to turn the Reveal sensitivity all the way up as shown below.

[image: auto-hide-launcher]